# scroll start point of a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-activity, workflow-activity, horizontalscrollview

In the method onCreate, I tried to put a series of TextView in HorizontalScrollView and then I tried to set the value of the scroll to a TextView. Not working. When I find the TextView I need, i put it in a class field and when the cycle that inflates the TextViex is over, i ask to my good one TextViev its getLeft(), and it return me always 0. If I try to scroll by arbitrary measure in onCreate, even that does not work.
What happens? How can i accomplish what i'm looking for?

Comment: Andrea Scarafoni :It is very diffcult to understand ur english, can u post ur code and screen shot of the output what u expecting and the screen shot of present output.

Comment: no thank you, what i needed was a Gallery and not a HorizontalScrollView.